# Is it possible to derive a custom boolean function from a truth table in terms of known boolean operators?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

And how would one do so?

I'm doing a programming project that requires me to propagate input signals through a circuit consisting of different types of logic gates. One of the gates I need to implement is a custom one whose truth table is:

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| Input 1 | Input 2 | Input 3 | Output |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|       0 |       0 |       0 |      1 |
|       0 |       0 |       1 |      1 |
|       0 |       1 |       0 |      0 |
|       0 |       1 |       1 |      0 |
|       1 |       0 |       0 |      1 |
|       1 |       0 |       1 |      0 |
|       1 |       1 |       0 |      0 |
|       1 |       1 |       1 |      0 |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I'm not terribly familiar with boolean functions, digital logic, etc. so any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you were designing with transistors, you could make a custom gate to implement this. But if you're programming a computer to simulate it, you're stuck with the logic operations offered by your programming language.

Comment: If you feel like a bit of studying, [Digital Logic Design](http://american.cs.ucdavis.edu/academic/ecs154a.sum14/postscript/cosc205.pdf) is a useful text. You could jump to page 27 "Combinational circuit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This could be done by inspection, or by [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Although there are different methods.

The most basic method is to express the output obtained from the truth table, as a sum of products or products of sums, following the rules of [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).
Thus, the *canonical expression* function described by the truth table is achieved.
By Karnaugh map, you can reduce that logic function.